# accidently deleted bootmgr (dual boot), heard you can use supergrub can create a new one? how?

Tags: dual-boot

I did the most stupid thing anyone can do and accidentally deleted bootmgr on my computer. from reading another forum someone said that supergrub has a option to make a new bootmgr so I dont get the 'bootmgr is missing' error. Also, if you can, do you know any other ways to recover the files, because I was stupid enough to delete it while on ubuntu (it isnt in recycle bin because It said it couldnt do that and instead asked if I wanted to delete it without moving it to recycle bin). HELP!

Edit: where is the windows repair console? (I can do the other option)

Comment: If you can start to boot, f8 usually gets you into the Windows repair console. Otherwise from a Windows repairCD or flash drive or a Windows installer: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Windows bootloader, boot to a Windows installer (the free Windows Technical Preview one will do) and select repair your computer after language selection. Choose Troubleshoot>Command Prompt, and run: `bootrec.exe /fixmbr`.

Comment: Whatever you do, do not install grub to any NTFS partition. Windows has essential boot info in the partition boot sector. You can run the fixMBR command but then will need to reinstall grub to MBR to dual boot. YOu probalby have to run the full set of Windows repair commands or auto fix three times from the Windows repair console.